# DL4J: How to calculate semantic similarity between two new sentences using GoogleNews vector

Tags: nlp, deeplearning4j, dl4j

I am just going through basic tutorials for DL4J. And I am planning to compare similarity between two unseen sentences.
I used a simple example to compare 2 words once W2V is done using `GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz`.
When I tried using GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz for sentence comparision like below:

```
File gModel = new File("GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz");
Word2Vec vecGoogle = WordVectorSerializer.readWord2VecModel(gModel);

ParagraphVectors vecGoogleForSentences = new ParagraphVectors.Builder()
.useExistingWordVectors(vecGoogle)
.build();

System.out.println(Transforms.cosineSim(vecGoogleForSentences.inferVector("I like bananas and mangoes"), vecGoogleForSentences.inferVector("I like mangoes")));
```

I get error:

> org.nd4j.linalg.exception.ND4JIllegalStateException: Model being
>   passed as existing has no syn1/syn1Neg available

Can someone please explain what I am hitting here or how I can compare 2 unseen sentences semantically using vector GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz?
What I am trying is based on suggestion given in [DL4J demo code](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples/blob/master/dl4j-examples/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/examples/nlp/paragraphvectors/ParagraphVectorsInferenceExample.java):

Much thanks in Advance !

Comment: Fwiw, the DL4J is active here: https://gitter.im/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way of doing it is just computing the mean vector of all the words in the sentence (sum the vectors divide by n) and compute the cosine similarity of those.

Comment: Hi Adam, So, you mean, one should calculate <word_vector>.getWordVectorMatrix(string) to get vector matrix for each word ?
After taking averages, how we can calculate cosine similarities between the vectors ?

Aint there already available APIs for this ?